# Typescript: Creating Array of Class instance inside another Class constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Whats is the best way of creating a class instance from JSON which has an array of other class as a member

```
class Someclass {
  memList: Mem[];
  constructor(data: any) {
    for(let i=0;i<data.mems.length;i++) {
      this.memList.push(new Mem(data.mems[i]));
    }
  }
 //methods
  ...
}

export class Mem {
 // Mem class with members 
}

Json
{
  mems: [
         {//here mem properties},
         {},
         {}
        ],
  someOtherProp: {}
}
```

What is the general practice followed in this scenario?

Looping inside the constructor and creating a new instance is considered a good approach?

Inside Mem class if it's creating a list of other class objects, will it slow down creating a class instance of Someclass?

Comment: You could use a map instead of a for but its still fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Someclass {
  memList: Mem[];
  constructor(data: any) {
    this.memList = data.mems.map(m => new Mem(m));
  }
 //methods
  ...
}
```

... is a nice concise way to do what you want, though your way is fine too - if you added `this.` before `memList`. Don't worry about slowing down construction of the class, unless you have an *enormous* data set, but then you probably have other problems anyway.